# Editing django admin change list item

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

So currently I have a django model admin page, with some extra fields specified. I want to be able to modify just 1 field so that instead of listing the value, I can click on it to go to a URL.

Let's say the model is Product, and the field is ID. Right now it shows ID but I want to be able to click on the ID on the change list to go to the following URL:

```
http://google.com/ID
```

The `http://google.com/` isn't saved anywhere.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by customizing "list_display" field of ModelAdmin:

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        # put all other fields you want to be shown in listing
        'id_link',
    )

    def id_link(self, obj):
        return 'http://google.com/' + self.id
    id_link.short_description = 'ID'
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display